Probability of having the same Name and DOB
I have a population of 40,000,000 who might call my company. They can provide first name, last name and DOB.
I am assuming that 1.9% of people in the population have the same first name, last name and date of birth as another person*.
When customers of my company (0.5% of the population) call my company, I want to be able to predict the number of false positives I'll get. The number of people who have identical names/DOB to my customers.
I have no idea how to do this, please help :)
*Computing number of people with the same name and date of birth based on sample data

You need data.  Specifically, because first name popularity changes (dramatically) over time, it won't suffice to use crude averages for the population: you need to know (or have a good estimate of) the distribution of frequencies of (first, last, DOB) triples within the population relevant to your company.

Thanks. I dont think that kind of data is available to me. If the same distribution was assumed, could I just take 1.9% of the expected call volumes as the false positive no.?

Back of an envelope: if you think there are $40,000,000 \times 0.019= 760,000$ people who match someone else and $380,000$ pairs of such people, and the probability both in a particular pair call you is $0.005^2= 0.000025$ then your expectation is  $9.5$ total pairs call you.  If you treat each individual in a pair as a "false positive" then double this to $19$. This is a small proportion of the call volume of $200,000$, just under $0.01%$:  (Different Henry - you probably do not have both my surname and my DoB)

Amazing, thanks Henry

@Henry The number of pairs of $k$ people is $k(k-1)/2,$ not $k/2$--far larger than you compute here.

@whuber If there are $k$ married people at a party, each married to one other person at the party, then there would be $\frac k2$ married couples at the party. (Married couple $\to$ pair, and party $\to$ population).

@Henry My point is that the answer depends heavily on the distribution of counts of groups of people sharing (first, last, DOB) values.  I presented an extreme example of the possibilities.
